# Solving $z^5 + z + 3 = 0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following equation for $z$:

> $$ z^5 + z + 3 = 0 $$

Where $z \in \mathbb{C} \quad $ ($\iff$it's a complex number)

How do I even begin? It would be nice if it were a quadratic, but it isn't. I guess I should try to factor the expression on the LHS, but I don't really see a way. I also tried expressing $z$ as $(xi + y)$ or $r\mathrm{e}^{\theta i}$ but it didn't help at all.

I'm not asking for complete solutions yet, just ideas please; I'm completely baffled as to how to even start.

Comment: Maybe you can use $z = x+iy$ and find $z^5$ by using binomial theorem.

Comment: You shouldn’t expect a formula for any root. You can find the one real root by Newton-Raphson, and from there I don’t know. You should be able to use other analytic methods for the two pairs of conjugate complex roots; I suppose if all else failed, you could use the Quartic Formula to solve the quartic, but that would be a horrible mess.

Comment: Well, why this polynomial, bertal ? By a standard trick, $z^5 + z + 1$ is divisible by $z^2 + z + 1.$ That is a more reasonable problem. That one happens because the nontrivial cube roots of unity must be roots, for each of those $z^5 = z^2$

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Turns out I accidentally misread the question (this was in an exam): the actual question was merely whether this equation has any roots. And AFAIK, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, indeed it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There do exists some formula for the roots of the equation $z^5+z+t = 0$ but all of them involve special functions. They are very far away from solving
the equation in any practical sense.

For example, when $t$ is real, the quintic equation has a unique real root.
This unique real root is known as the [Bring raidcal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical). It can be expressed in terms of 
[generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function):

$${\rm BR}(t) = -t\,{}_4F_3\left(\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45; \frac12, \frac34, \frac54; -5\left(\frac{5t}{4}\right)^4\right)$$
When $t = 3$, throwing following command

- `-3*HypergeometricPFQ[{1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5},{1/2,3/4,5/4},- 3125*3^4/256]`

to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) gives us
$$BR(3) \approx -1.13299756588506526672...$$

This matches the value of the unique real root of $z^5 + z + 3 = 0$ computed numerically.

If you want to know more about Bring radical, the wiki entry linked above will be a good start. Unfortunately, that entry has many typos among the formula. If you want to use the formula there to locate other complex roots, you should re-derive them yourself to ensure their correctness.

Another good source for this sort of stuff is Bruce King's book [Beyond the Quartic Equation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817648364). Highly recommended!